# twinkle: chars are shown as rectangles

Tags: fonts, qt, vcxsrv

Environment: host with windows 10, kitty, vcxsrv

guest with centos6, twinkle

On windows I have start vcxsrv and kitty with Xforward and connect to centos6. When in kitty I start twinkle I see this

[image: twinkle]

When I start for example xterm it looks normal.

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

After

```
yum groupinstall Xfce
```

twinkle looks normal.